# why celery autodiscover isnt mapping tasks from different folders?

Tags: python, redis, celery

I Have the following structure for celery project where it doesn't need the use of django / flask, but however I am trying to map my tasks based on the celery structure layout from this site https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/_modules/celery/app/base.html#Celery.autodiscover_tasks  I could some issues with autodiscovery, but I still have zero tasks mapped from different folders

```
.
├── docker-compose.yml
├── LICENSE
├── logs
├── README.md
├── redis
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── redis.conf
└── thirdparty
    ├── appone
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── tasks.py
    ├── apptwo
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── tasks.py
    └── celery_tasks
        ├── celery.py
        ├── __init__.py
        └── settings.py
```

thirdparty/celery_tasks/celery.py

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery("thirdparty")
app.config_from_object('celery_tasks.settings', namespace="CELERY")
app.autodiscover_tasks(['celery_tasks.appone', 'celery_tasks.apptwo'])
```

thirdparty/celery_tasks/settings.py

```
from celery.schedules import crontab
from datetime import timedelta


CELERY_BROKER_URL = "redis://localhost:6379/0"
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "redis://localhost:6379/0"
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    "sample_task": {
        "task": "appone.tasks.add",
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=30),
    },
    "send_email_report": {
        "task": "apptwo.tasks.mult",
        "schedule": crontab(minute="*"),
    },
}

# run task every 30 minutes
CELERY_BEAT_INTERVAL = 30 * 60
```

thirdparty/apptwo/tasks.py

```
import time
from celery_tasks.celery import app

@app.task
def mult(x, y):
    print('start apptwo mult function')
    time.sleep(10)
    print('result:', x * y)
    return x * y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us focus on this path tree:

```
└── thirdparty
    ├── appone
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── tasks.py
    ├── apptwo
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── tasks.py
    └── celery_tasks
        ├── celery.py
        ├── __init__.py
        └── settings.py
```

Relative to the outer project (as the sources root), the list of modules are:

```
thirdparty.appone.tasks (contains add)
thirdparty.apptwo.tasks (contains mult)
thirdparty.celery_tasks.celery (contains app)
thirdparty.celery_tasks.settings (contains CELERY_BROKER_URL, CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND, etc.)
```

Relative to thirdparty (as the sources root), the list of modules are:

```
appone.tasks (contains add)
apptwo.tasks (contains mult)
celery_tasks.celery (contains app)
celery_tasks.settings (contains CELERY_BROKER_URL, CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND, etc.)
```

Based on how you imported the celery app from thirdparty/apptwo/tasks.py we can say that you have designed your thirdparty to be the sources root:

```
from celery_tasks.celery import app  # If the sources root was the outer project, then this would be -> from thirdparty.celery_tasks.celery import app
```

How you accessed ./thirdparty/appone/ and ./thirdparty/apptwo/ is wrong:

```
app.autodiscover_tasks(['celery_tasks.appone', 'celery_tasks.apptwo'])
```

Why? The module celery_tasks doesn't have .appone nor .apptwo. It only has .celery and .settings. If you look at the list of modules I described above, this is the correct path:

```
app.autodiscover_tasks(['appone', 'apptwo'])  # This assumes that thirdparty is your sources root, thus you wouldn't write it as thirdparty.appone nor thirdparty.apptwo
```

### Further reading

Given that `thirdparty` is the sources root, you have to format your imports to always be relative fromm it e.g. `from celery_tasks.celery import app` and **not** relative to the outer project e.g. `from thirdparty.celery_tasks.celery import app` **nor** e.g. `from myproj.thirdparty.celery_tasks.celery import app`.

Then, you have to tell PYTHONPATH about it so that you can perform imports relative to the thirdparty directory (such as how you did with `from celery_tasks.celery import app`).

```
export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/path/to/myproj/thirdparty
```

Why? Let's say you just defined PYTHONPATH up to the outer project:

```
export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/path/to/myproj
```

Then, you have to import the modules relative to myproj and not relative to thirdparty. So the way you would import inside thirdparty/apptwo/tasks.py would have been:

```
from thirdparty.celery_tasks.celery import app
```

While your autodiscover would have been:

```
app.autodiscover_tasks(['thirdparty.appone', 'thirdparty.apptwo'])
```